# Evaluate all formula cells in cell - java Apache poi

Tags: java, apache-poi, xssf, evaluate

I am currently using

```
XSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateAllFormulaCells(wb);
```

However, this leaves formula in the cell.

I read similar questions to remove the formula from cell and keep only value using

```
evaluator.evaluateInCell(cell);
```

How can I use evaluateInCell with all formula cells?
One way would be to loop over all cells, is there any other way?

I want to achieve a sheet without any formulas having just calculated values

Comment: "One way would be to loop over all cells, is there any other way?" No, that's exactly what `FormulaEvaluator.evaluateAllFormulaCells` also does. No magic available in programming until now.

Comment: I was just wondering if me using a loop for evaluation would be slow as compared to the evaluateAllFormulaCells implementation. Suppose I have a cell formula referencing to another cell whose formula is already evaluated. In that case, cached calculation could speed up the process and hence was searching for an alternative already implemented instead of looping over all cells. I'm not sure of the implementation of Formula evaluator. Thanks

Comment: Look at [BaseFormulaEvaluator.evaluateAllFormulaCells](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_5_0_0/src/java/org/apache/poi/ss/formula/BaseFormulaEvaluator.java?view=markup#l255) to see the implementation. Then do the same only using `evaluator.evaluateInCell` instead of `evaluator.evaluateFormulaCell`.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, I will check.

Answer (score 0):

See the Snipet here. For more [Details](https://www.baeldung.com/apache-poi-read-cell-value-formula)

```
// existing Workbook setup

FormulaEvaluator evaluator = workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator(); 

// existing Sheet, Row, and Cell setup

if (cell.getCellType() == CellType.FORMULA) {
    switch (evaluator.evaluateFormulaCell(cell)) {
        case BOOLEAN:
            System.out.println(cell.getBooleanCellValue());
            break;
        case NUMERIC:
            System.out.println(cell.getNumericCellValue());
            break;
        case STRING:
            System.out.println(cell.getStringCellValue());
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to convert all formula cells to value cells